# Trim and concat the video files based on start and end time

Tags: ffmpeg

I will be having 'n' number of video files, 1 min duration each (with timestamps)
(say I started recording at 12.00.00 and stopped at 1.00.00, then 60 video files will be generated)
based on the Input: (start time (say 12.00.59) & end time(say 12.02.39), I need to trim and merge the files.
start and end can be in same 1 min video (single file) or it can be in different files

I have tried simply by using system() functions for invoking the ffmpeg API

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    if((argc < 3) || (argc >3))
    {
        cout << "Execute in provided format" << "\n";
        cout << "binary $start_time(xx:xx:xx)as xxxxxx $end_time(xx:xx:xx)as xxxxxx (i.e)without ':'" << "\n";
        cout << "For Example for 18.30.10 18.35.14 input as 183010 183514" << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    uint32_t start_time =(uint32_t)atoi(argv[1]); 
    uint32_t end_time =(uint32_t)atoi(argv[2]);

    uint32_t total_time = ((end_time/100) - (start_time/100));


    std::string file_path("/home/event_clip/test/vfiles/");
    file_path += std::to_string((start_time/100));
    file_path += ".mp4";

    const char* fname = file_path.c_str();
    cout << fname << "\n";

    FILE *file = fopen(file_path.c_str(), "r+");
    if(file == NULL){
        cout << "video file not yet created";
    }else{
        if(total_time < 1){
            cout << "Req video is in single file" << "\n";
            cout << "Trim is enough" << "\n";


            char buf[64];
            snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "ffmpeg -t 00:00:%u -i %u.mp4 -ss 00:00:%u trim.mp4 -y",end_time%100,(start_time/100),start_time%100);
            system(buf);
        }else{
            FILE *concat_fp ;
            concat_fp = fopen("/home/event_clip/test/vfiles/concat_files.txt","w");
            fclose(concat_fp);
            concat_fp = fopen("/home/event_clip/test/vfiles/concat_files.txt","a+");
            cout << "Required video is in " << total_time+1 << " files" << "\n";
            cout << "Trim and merge has to be done" << "\n";

            /* Trim start file */
            char startbuf[64];
            snprintf(startbuf, sizeof(startbuf), "ffmpeg -t 00:01:00 -i %u.mp4 -ss 00:00:%u concatstart.mp4 -y",(start_time/100),start_time%100);
            system(startbuf);

            fprintf(concat_fp,"file './concatstart.mp4'\n");

            /* Trim end file */
            char endbuf[64];
            snprintf(endbuf, sizeof(endbuf), "ffmpeg -t 00:00:%u -i %u.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 concatend.mp4 -y",end_time%100,(start_time/100));
            system(endbuf);

            if(total_time > 2){
                for(int i = 1; i < (total_time+1); i++){
                    fprintf(concat_fp,"file './%u.mp4'\n",((start_time/100)+i));
                }
            }
            fprintf(concat_fp,"file './concatend.mp4'\n");
            fclose(concat_fp);
            char concatbuf[67];
            snprintf(concatbuf, sizeof(concatbuf), "ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i concat_files.txt -c copy concat.mp4 -y");
            system(concatbuf);
        }
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me adding ffmpeg 'C' API's using libav

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi tetech, I have updated my question, Please check and revert back if you know anything, other than commenting "What have you tried so far?"